# C code help, loops and sum of multiples

Tags: c, loops

I am stuck and I could use a fresh set of eyes.

Here's the question:
 Create a loop that will calculate the sum of the multiples of 8 that are between 100 and 500.  Output the sum.

Here's my code

My issue is, when if I say... while ( multiple > 100 && multiple < 500) my only output is "press any key to continue". If I edit it so say while (multiple < 500) it runs fine but includes the multiples below 100 which I don't need.

I don't understand why it won't let me say  while ( multiple > 100 && multiple < 500)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int number = 8, count = 1, multiple = 0, sum = 0;
while (multiple < 500) {
    multiple = number * count;
    count = ++count;
    printf("Your multiple is: %i \n", multiple);

}

sum = multiple * count;
count = ++count;
printf("Your sum of the multiples are: %i \n", sum);


system("pause");
```

Comment: This is an excellent first question here. You've explained what you're trying to do, the problem you're having, and included the relevant code, all without having to be asked for it.  I wish more new users went through that effort to get things right. Thanks!

Comment: `count = ++count;` Hint: sequence point.

Comment: What do you expect `count = ++count;` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't let you say `while(multiple > 100)` because `multiple` starts out at 0. You will never enter the loop.

You want:

```
while (multiple < 500) {
    multiple = number * count;
    count = ++count;
    if (multiple > 100) {
        printf("Your multiple is: %i \n", multiple);
    }
}
```

Comment: @nhouser9 If it was a snake, it would have bit me. Thank you

Comment: @ken white Yeah, I see what I did now. It's been a long day and I feel stupid for missing the initialization to 0 being the issue.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Neither is zero, but that's irrelevant. Why start at zero? (You're right; it should have started below 100, but still not at zero.)

Comment: @David: Zero is not a multiple of 8 between 100 and 500, unless I've gotten way too out of date with modern math.

Answer (score 0):

Hi simple answer is if you just initialise count =101; 
Code will run properly and you will get right answer because you need the sum between 100 and 500.

Why to waste some processing time on which you are not looking for.

Comment: Straight up wrong - this will print "101, 109" etc. None of the numbers printed will be multiples of 8.